# Среднее значение параметра объекта

Tags: javascript, jquery

Получаю Массив внутри объекты с данными

```
 data = [
    {position: "10", page: "1", date: "16", product_id: "1"},
    {position: "20", page: "2", date: "16", product_id: "2"},
    {position: "30", page: "3", date: "20", product_id: "3"},
    {position: "40", page: "4", date: "20", product_id: "3"}
 ]
```

Как можно получить среднее значение `position` для объекта с одинаковыми `date` и `product_id`

P.S. это нужно для построения точки на графике, среднее значение позиции определенного продукта за определенный день.
Как это можно реализовать? третий день не могу придумать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const data = [
  {position: "10", page: "1", date: "16", product_id: "1"},
  {position: "20", page: "2", date: "16", product_id: "2"},
  {position: "30", page: "3", date: "20", product_id: "3"},
  {position: "40", page: "4", date: "20", product_id: "3"}
];

/*
  отсортируем по категориям date и product_id
  в итоге получим объект, где ключ это пара date_product_id,
  а значение это массив из элеменетов position
  ключ можно использовать не комбинированный, а иерархичный, для более 
  глубокого анализа
*/

let results = data.reduce((result, current) => {
  const key = current.date + '_' + current.product_id;
  result[key] ? result[key].push(current.position) :
    (result[key] = [current.position]);
  return result;
}, {});

// теперь можно делать анализ. Пройдемся по объекту, сложим значения по ключам и получим искомый результат

for (let key of Object.keys(results)) {
  const positions = results[key];
  console.log(positions.reduce(
                (position, current) => position + +current, 0) / positions.length)
}
```

Синтаксис ES6

Comment: круто, спасибо огромное)

Answer (score 2):

```js
var data = [
    {position: "10", page: "1", date: "16", product_id: "1"},
    {position: "20", page: "2", date: "16", product_id: "2"},
    {position: "30", page: "3", date: "20", product_id: "3"},
    {position: "40", page: "4", date: "20", product_id: "3"}
 ];
 
var result = {};

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if (!result[data[i].product_id])
    result[data[i].product_id] = {};
  var product = result[data[i].product_id];
  if (!product[data[i].date])
    product[data[i].date] = { count: 0, sum: 0 };
  var collect = product[data[i].date];
  collect.count = collect.count + 1;
  collect.sum = collect.sum + +data[i].position;
}

for(var pKey in result) {
  for (var cKey in result[pKey]) {
    result[pKey][cKey].average = result[pKey][cKey].sum / result[pKey][cKey].count;
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Я через генерацию ассоциативных цепочек делал [https://jsfiddle.net/ydw0gtf2/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/ydw0gtf2/2/), но ваш код конечно же гораздо проще  :)